# UIGraphics drawInRect: crashes on 4S device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, graphics, uigraphicscontext

Basically, i do:

```
- (UIImage *)addPreviewImageToImage:(UIImage *)backImage
{
    UIImage *newImage;

    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sampleImage" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *frontImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];

    float scale = 1.0f;
    CGRect rectBack = CGRectMake(0, 0, scale * backImage.size.width, scale * backImage.size.height);

    CGRect rectFront = [self rectForFrontElementOfSize:frontImage.size overElementOfSize:rectBack.size mediaType:kMediaTypeImage];

    // Begin context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rectBack.size, YES, 0); // opaque = YES

    // draw images
    @autoreleasepool { // no effect
        [backImage drawInRect:rectBack]; // where the crash occurs, backImage is about 4 Mo
    }
    [frontImage drawInRect:rectFront];

    // grab context
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // end context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This works fine on iPhone 5 or more (iOS7) but crashes 80% of the time on 4S on drawInRect: call.
How can I optimize this code ? Would writing the backImage on the disk and then get it via contentsOfFile be more efficient ? Any ideas ?

EDIT (crash details):
After receiving memory warnings, Xcode terminates the app stating :

> "Terminated due to Memory Pressure"

By using breakpoints I know this occurs when executing drawInRect:backImage (which is a picture from the camera)

rectBack description before crash:

> (CGRect) rectBack = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=2448, height=3264)

Note:
Having set opaque argument as YES in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and reducing the scale argument seems to make it work, but I am loosing quality and I'd like to know if there's something wrong in the logic

Comment: What is the error? Is `rectBack` valid at the times of the crash?

Comment: Just tried your code on my 4S, no crashes.

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: Does it crash because of memory warning?

Comment: Xcode terminates the app stating "Terminated due to Memory Pressure", by using breakpoints I know this occurs when executing drawInRect:backImage (which is a picture from the camera), and yes, the app receives memory warnings just before stopping. Here is rectBack description before the crash (it is valid): (CGRect) rectBack = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=2448, height=3264)